# Is there a work around for request timeout on CN1 when connectivity is poor

Tags: codenameone

I have the following error from the logs. I'm thinking this timed out thrown by the server. But on the server there is no timeout duration has been set. So my question is there something on CN1 we can add to try to complete the request for certain time(Especially when internet connectivity is poor) and re-try kind of functionality available. Please advise.

> [Network Thread] 58:51:51,888 - The request timed out.                                                                            [Network Thread] 58:51:51,898 - Exception: java.io.IOException - The request timed out.
>            java.io.IOException
>               at com_codename1_io_ConnectionRequest.performOperation:884
>               at com_codename1_io_NetworkManager_NetworkThread.run:325
>               at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
>               at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
>                   [EDT] 58:51:52,3 - Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - 0 out of: 0
>                           java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>               at java_util_ArrayList.get:328
>               at .finishAppointment:2737
>               at _forms_ConfirmationForm.lambda$new$1:145
>               at forms_ConfirmationForm__Lambda_2.actionPerformed:330
>               at com_codename1_ui_util_EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent:349
>               at com_codename1_ui_Button.fireActionEvent:571
>               at com_codename1_ui_Button.released:605
>               at com_codename1_ui_Button.pointerReleased:709
>               at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3503
>               at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4621
>               at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2249
>               at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1212
>               at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1130
>               at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
>               at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
>               at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153

Please see the attached code for server communication.

```
 ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest(URL_PREFIX + appName + API_SUFFIX
                + "Verification/apt/" + apt, true) {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                String s = Util.readToString(input);
                response.add(s);    
            }

            @Override
            protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                String body = "{      \n"
                        + "   \"FinishTimeEpoch\":" + retrieveModifiedLongDuration(endTimeFinal) * 60000;
                if (startTimeFinal != -1) {
                    body += ",\n   \"StartTimeEpoch\":" + retrieveModifiedLongDuration(startTimeFinal) * 60000;
                } 
                body += "\n}";                
                if (shouldWriteUTFAsGetBytes()) {
                    os.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                } else {
                    OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                    w.write(body);
                }
            }
        };

        r.setHttpMethod("PUT");
        r.setContentType("application/json");
        r.setFailSilently(true);
        r.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a connection timeout which means the timeout occurred before connecting to the server. It took too long to connect.

You can increase the timeout but it might be better to actually decrease it and retry more. You can set the timeout either on the connection request itself or on the `NetworkManager` to set it globally. See `setTimeout`.